# JavaScript Syntax​Error: missing ) After Argument List in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to execute JavaScript code in Python using selenium. But I'm getting the error down below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
```

Here's my code:

```py
def selenium_process():
driver = webdriver.Chrome(data[3])
x = 0
driver.get(data[0])
while x <= postCount:
    driver.execute_script(f"window.open({data[0]});")
    x = x + 1
    if(x>postCount):
        time.sleep(10000000)
```

Note: I'm getting array elements as an input from a GUI and then append them into `data[]` array.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes around the data when the data is a string and not a variable (or int or float - but this wouldn't be a valid argument for `window.open` anyway):

```
driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{data[0]}');")
```